# Join lists with dictionaries for given interval

Tags: python, dictionary, join

I have the following - maybe very simple - question.

I have a dictionary with several keys and values. For my relevant key, i have 10 entries, but i only need the entries 3-6 to be part of my string (simplified, in reality i have 1000 entries).

So far my code is this, but it plots me all 10 keys. I would like to make the program slice the list and print only elements 3-6 from `mykey`.

```
mydict = {"key1": "red",
          "key2": "grass",
          "key3": 2020,
          "mykey": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}

string = ", ".join(f'{q:}' for q in mydict["mykey"]) + "\n"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but one way to take elements with indices 3-6 from the list would be
`", ".join(f'{q:}' for q in mydict["mykey"][3:7])`

Comment: perfect that solved it and is the way i was looking for! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To slice a list in python use the `[]` operator.**

---

### For example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(l[1:6:2])
```

This code will print all the 2nd elements between 1 to 6 (exclude), so the output is:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

The `[]` operator works in this way `[start : stop : step]` where `start`, `stop`, and `step` are integers.

### In your code you can write this:

```py
mydict = {"key2": "grass",
          "key3": 2020,
          "mykey": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
         }

string = ", ".join(str(q) for q in mydict["mykey"][3:7]) + "\n"

# or in a simple way
string = ", ".join(mydict["mykey"][3:7]) + "\n"
```

Comment: just now, that works as desired. thanks a lot! i was missing the [3:7] bracket.

Comment: great. the last line simplifies it even further